# Deleting a line and inserting in IntelliJ Idea Ultimate

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, osx-yosemite, intellij-15

So when I open a new class, it is not in insert mode, I am not sure but seems like when I press i, it goes into insert mode (like vim editor). Also when a line is selected, if I press the delete button it doesn't delete it and had to delete the line character by character. This problem is recent and I wonder if I have accidentally messed up with a setting. I don't have this problem in IntelliJ community edition.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds irritating! Make sure you're not in vim mode (Tools -> VimEmulator), you might want to remove the keyboard shortcut for it too. Also make sure you're not in column mode (Edit -> column mode).

Edit: Uncheck the Vim Emulator
[image]